# Using monero-wallet-cli to do a transfer after version 0.14+

Tags: monero-wallet-cli, transfer

I know ring size is not required anymore so has the transfer command changed after the v0.14+ monero cli wallet update?

- How do you send monero using the transfer command now with payment id?
- Do you have to do anything else special with the transfer command after v0.14?

Comment: Note that sending to long payment IDs has to be enabled via a startup flag:

https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/11014/how-do-i-use-long-payment-ids-in-cli-v0-14-gui-v0-14/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I know ring size is not required anymore so has the transfer command changed after the v0.14+ monero cli wallet update?

It's still required by the protocol but the wallet sets the ring-size to 11 without the need to specify in the transfer command. The command and it's parameters are unchanged (backwards compatible) however.

> How do you send monero using the transfer command now with payment id?
>   Do you have to do anything else special with the transfer command after v0.14?

It works the same way as before.

```
[wallet 456789]: help transfer
Command usage: 
  transfer [index=<N1>[,<N2>,...]] [<priority>] [<ring_size>] (<URI> | <address> <amount>) [<payment_id (obsolete)>]

Command description: 
  Transfer <amount> to <address>. If the parameter "index=<N1>[,<N2>,...]" is specified, the wallet uses outputs received by addresses of those indices. If omitted, the wallet randomly chooses address indices to be used. In any case, it tries its best not to combine outputs across multiple addresses. <priority> is the priority of the transaction. The higher the priority, the higher the transaction fee. Valid values in priority order (from lowest to highest) are: unimportant, normal, elevated, priority. If omitted, the default value (see the command "set priority") is used. <ring_size> is the number of inputs to include for untraceability. Multiple payments can be made at once by adding URI_2 or <address_2> <amount_2> etcetera (before the payment ID, if it's included)
```

You will however get a warning:

```
Unencrypted payment IDs are bad for privacy: ask the recipient to use subaddresses instead
```

Comment: it also requires the enable long payment id flag when starting up the cli wallet.